# Unkown Opcode from TFTP Client when looked at in wireshark

Tags: c++, winsock2, tftp

Good evening everyone.

I'm having trouble creating a TFTP client for an assignment in C++ that uses #include

I'm sending the char buffer:

> buffer={'0','2','f','i','l','e','n','a','m','e','0','o','c','t','e','t','0'};

Using the code:

> sendto(sock,buffer,strlen(buffer), 0, (sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(sockaddr));

But when I look at this transfer in the WireShark it says "Opcode: Unknown (12338)" when I look at the Opcode portion of the packet. 
Even though it has selected the opcode from the string

[image]

I'm absolutely stuck, any help would be appreciated. I'm pretty sure if I can send and receive a message I can handle the rest pretty easily.

**Just throwing down here what I did but the marked answer was basically it**
Used the BYTE from winsock2 (don't know if I need to but better safe than sorry)

> buffer={(BYTE)0,(BYTE)2,'f','i','l','e','n','a','m','e',(BYTE)0,'o','c','t','e','t',(BYTE)0};

and

> sendto(sock,buffer,sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(sockaddr));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `strlen(buffer)` but `sizeof(buffer)`...

strlen stops couting characters at the first occurrence of `'\0'` - so it returns unspecified value for your buffer array since `'\0'` is not present in your buffer.

If you want to start your buffer with opcode `02` then pass it as integers not their digit representation:

```
buffer={0,2,'f','i','l','e','n','a','m','e','0','o','c','t','e','t','0'};
//      ^ ^  simple numbers - not characters - not sure about rest of your buffer
```

Comment: It is basically what you said but I convert the decimal using the BYTE cast from winsock2. So I'm marking your answer as correct.

Comment: Originally I thought you were suggesting \0 was in the buffer, but later realized that strlen() will return lengths much larger than the buffer. You should probably cast the first 2 entries in the buffer either to a (char) or (uint_8)

Comment: @Brady - not sure if this casting is needed - maybe with some pedantic  compiler options. C++ allows here implicit casting. Anyway OP declared  to add this casting in previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

12338 in decimal is 0x30, 0x32 in hex, which corresponds to '0' and '2' from your buffer.

Your using ascii chars, but you need to use a decimal/integer, by setting them to `(char) 0x00` and `(char) 0x02` in your buffer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm really tired at this point. If it is any consolation the original version I had created looked gorgeous.